# Component loses datasource location when adding it into a rendering variant

Tags: sxa

I am trying to include the video component into a rendering variant of one of my components. I don't want to set the datasource on the rendering variant its self, I want the user to set the datasource when the component is added to the page by clicking the "video" icon, the same way it would usually work when using the video component.

It seems that when you add the video component into a rendering variant it "forgets" its datasource location that is set on the rendering.

I've provided a video below on a new instance that outlines my problem a bit better (I've used promo in that scenario, on my live environment it's a custom version of promo)

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVXQtxPjir4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a support ticket to Sitecore regarding this issue when using `Sitecore 9.1.1` and `SXA 1.8.1`. I've had confirmation that this has been reproduced and is in fact a bug, it has been logged under `#337905`.